# Identify all users presence states in Lync with an windows service

Tags: c#, lync-2013, skype-for-business

I got a simple requirement, but I don't know how I can it solve in a service. 
I Use the Microsoft.Lync.Model and following code

```
LyncClient.GetClient();
foreach (Group _Group in lyncClient.ContactManager.Groups)
{ 
  if (_Group.Type == GroupType.CustomGroup)
  {
     GetGroupContacts(_Group);
  }
}
```

The GeGroupContacts contains only the following code

```
  // Iterate on the contacts in the group.
  foreach (Contact _Contact in group)
  {

    Console.WriteLine("{0}  ist {1}", 
    _Contact.GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType.DisplayName),                
    _Contact.GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType.Activity));

    }
```

These will iterate the existing groupd and list all users and there state in the console. This works very well. So how I understand, this use my own credentials to performing the operations.

Is it possible to get the presence states within a windows service with a "managed" account. So that it can be created a list that holds the presence of the users for evacuation purposes?

Does there exist an other solution for this?
I think Lync 2013 and S4B doesn't differ in their api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write a server based solution then I would suggest that the client API isn't a good fit, instead look at the UCMA https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn454984(v=office.15).aspx.  UCMA is an API that allows you to write server based solutions that respond to events across your Lync/Skype environment rather than to just a single user.